# How to determine whether pruning of decision tree is necessary?

Tags: r, cart

I am really new to decision trees. I constructed classification tree (estimate certification using grade and assignment) and calculated cp:

```
c.tree1 <- rpart(certified ~ grade + assignment, method="class", data=M1)
printcp(c.tree1)
```

The result shows that there are three layers:

```
Classification tree:
rpart(formula = certified ~ grade + assignment, data = M1, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] assignment grade     

Root node error: 275/1000 = 0.275

n= 1000 

        CP nsplit rel error   xerror      xstd
1 0.923636      0  1.000000 1.000000 0.0513455
2 0.058182      1  0.076364 0.076364 0.0164880
3 0.010000      2  0.018182 0.018182 0.0081108
```

In this case, how can I decide if I need to take out the last layer?
My naive thinking is that because the 1% in the third layer is too trivial so that the third layer is not so necessary.

Is there any theory or concept I need to know to better understand that? Can any one recommend some readings? Thank you so much!

Comment: You are looking for the minimum value of CP, which in your case is at the end, so there is no pruning required of your tree.